# Why Isn't Google Analytics Event Firing/Saving?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I've got a google analytics tracker loaded into an iFrame:

```
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-my-id-here');
  ga('set', 'location', 'http://foo.com/bar');
  ga('set', 'title', 'Awesome');

  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I've also got custom Javascript trying to track events in a rich-client application on the same page, which has a reference to the ga instance above, and tries to send an event:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'my_category', 'my_event', 'my_value');
```

When I load the page I see the initial pageview tracked properly.  When I click and fire off the custom event tracking, the JavaScript executes and does not throw an error.  It also does not register any event.

Comment: Are you sure it is not attempting to fire and you're getting redirected to a new page too soon? What does your code that execute it look like? Using a HTTP proxy tool like Fiddler or Charles Proxy, do you see the request?

Comment: I've got a JS app on the page using jQuery to track click events and interactions.  I'm using the Chrome Inspector to monitor network requests and the JS console for debugging statements or errors.  I see the initial AJAX call to track the pageview, but nothing for the events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being an issue of JavaScript scoping.

The `analytics.js` application only works when all calls are appropriately within the same Javascript scope.  I was trying to fire a GA event within a different page scope (due to an embedded JS app and iFrames, it's complicated).

The solution was the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-my-id');
  ga('set', 'hostname', 'awesome.com');
  ga('set', 'location', '/path/to/awesome');
  ga('set', 'referrer', 'REFERRER_VALUE');
  ga('set', 'title', 'Awesome App');

  ga('send', 'pageview');

  window.trackGAEvent = function(eventName, value) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'awesome_app', eventName, value);
  }
</script>
```

The trick was encapsulating the `ga` event `send` call.  I can call this method from other contexts by drilling down the DOM, but I can't call the GA app directly from outside the proper context.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure page you're trying to call following snippte has analytics.js loaded (if it's in iframe)

```
ga('send', 'event', 'my_category', 'my_event', 'my_value');
```

Comment: This is the code I was already using.  The issue ended up being something else, I'll post the answer.